# Selectores css "~" no selecciona valores desde el principio

Tags: javascript, css, selectores-css, estilos

Buen dia, tengo una lista de elementos "**<**li**>**" creada con datos que saco de una database. Es algo así:

```
[.....MÁS.....]

var html ='';
variable.forEach(function(e){

[.....MÁS.....]

            if(emisor == mail){
              var classs = "mensajeder";
              var li = "d-flex flex-row-reverse djk";
            }else{
              var classs = "mensajeizq";
              var li = "d-flex flex-row ljk";
            }

[.....MÁS.....]

html +=`<li class="`+li+`" id="`+key+`">
          <div class="`+classs+`  d-flex ">
             <div class="menpp">`+mensaje+`</div>
          </div>
          <div class="mensll `+key+`">&nbsp;`+hora+`&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
        </li>`;

[.....MÁS.....]

});

[.....MÁS.....]
```

Y luego el css que le agregé para probar su funcionamiento es:

```
.djk~.ljk{
        border:1px solid black;
}

.ljk~.djk{
        border:1px solid blue;
}
```

Sin embargo, el resultado es que con los primeros "**<**li**>**" (ya sea de una u otra forma) no sucede nada... y no entiendo por qué   ¿Alguien sabe como solucionarlo?

Comment: Hola Damián MV, ¿podrías crear un [mcve] en el que podamos ver el código generado? El problema no termina de quedar claro cuál es el problema, qué es lo que quieres que suceda y qué es lo que está sucediendo.

Comment: Te recomiendo que leas esta documentación sobre los [Selectores de hermanos generales](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator). Es posible que tus primeros `<li>` no se estén precediendo bien entre sí como para que se apliquen los estilos.

Answer (score 1):

Como ya te han comentado, el error se debe a que no estas aplicando estilos a los primeros `<li>`, ya que siempre estas modificando a *"los hermanos que siguien a..."*.

[Combinador general de hermanos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#combinadores)

> El combinador `~` selecciona hermanos. Esto quiere decir que el segundo elemento sigue al primero (no necesariamente de forma inmediata) y ambos comparten el mismo elemento padre.
> **Sintaxis:** `A ~ B`
> **Ejemplo:** La regla `p ~ span` se aplicará a todos los elementos `<span>` **que siguen un elemento** `<p>`.

#### Solución:

En este caso particular, diría que no hace falta saber *"¿soy el hermano que siguiente a..?"* para establecer el estilo que debe tener el elemento.

Se puede simplificar así:

```css
.ljk {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.djk {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="d-flex flex-row-reverse djk">
    <div class="mensajeder d-flex">
      <div class="menpp">Mensaje 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mensll">&nbsp;Hora&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
  </li>
  <li class="d-flex flex-row-reverse djk">
    <div class="mensajeder d-flex">
      <div class="menpp">Mensaje 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mensll">&nbsp;Hora&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
  </li>
  <li class="d-flex d-flex flex-row ljk">
    <div class="mensajeizq d-flex">
      <div class="menpp">Mensaje 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mensll">&nbsp;Hora&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
  </li>
  <li class="d-flex d-flex flex-row ljk">
    <div class="mensajeizq d-flex">
      <div class="menpp">Mensaje 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mensll">&nbsp;Hora&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
  </li>
  <li class="d-flex flex-row-reverse djk">
    <div class="mensajeder d-flex">
      <div class="menpp">Mensaje 5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mensll">&nbsp;Hora&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
  </li>
  <li class="d-flex d-flex flex-row ljk">
    <div class="mensajeizq d-flex">
      <div class="menpp">Mensaje 6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mensll">&nbsp;Hora&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
  </li>
  <li class="d-flex d-flex flex-row ljk">
    <div class="mensajeizq d-flex">
      <div class="menpp">Mensaje 6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mensll">&nbsp;Hora&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```